# How do I show a div below the each table row using bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Well, In my website User page all users are showing in **Bootstrap Table**. I'm trying to showing a **hidden content** bellow the each row after click on the row but It's showing the hidden content top of the table ? It's almost done. Can you tell me what is the wrong in my code ?

**Here is my full code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="resources/syntax/shCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="resources/demo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var name = $('td', this).eq(0).text();

    } );
} );
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<?php
$getUser = mysql_query("select * from members ORDER BY user_id DESC");
$num = mysql_num_rows($getUser);
?>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Kit type</th>                       
</tr>
</thead>                
<tbody>             


<?php
$i = 0;
while($search_result =  mysql_fetch_array($getUser)){
    $i++;

    $uid = (int) $search_result['user_id']; 
    $fname =  $search_result['fname'];  
    $lname  = $search_result['lname'];                  
    $company  = $search_result['company'];                  
    $position  = $search_result['position'];    
    $status  = $search_result['status'];    

    echo "<tr data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#collapse$i'>";                                 
    echo "<td class='row' $class valign='top'>$fname</td>";
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$lname</td>";                
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$company</td>";
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$position</td>";
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$status</td>";
    echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$kittype</td>";  
    ?>

    <div id="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <p>Hello print <?php echo $i; ?></p>
    </div>

    <?php
    echo "</tr>";   
}//while statement
?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:**

```
echo "<tr data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion' href='#collapse$i'>";                                 
echo "<td class='row' $class valign='top'>$fname</td>";
echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$lname</td>";                
echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$company</td>";
echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$position</td>";
echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$status</td>";
echo "<td class='row' $class  valign='top'>$kittype</td>";  
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";                                    
echo "<td colspan='6'>";    
<div id="collapse<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<p>Hello print <?php echo $i; ?></p>
</div>
<?php
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

**if I use this new row then first page is blank and in second page hidden div is not working after click on a row.**

Comment: ps: you can replace `<?php echo $i; ?>` with `<?=$i?>`

Comment: Start by writing [valid html](http://validator.w3.org/), you can't put a div there.

Comment: @Quentin what I need to do ?

Comment: @Quentin if I use `<tr><td></td></tr>` then it also show the hidden content to the top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not valid use of HTML to just throw a div inside a table. That doesn't make sense to the browser. To accomplish what you want to do, you'd need to close your row after your last `<td>` element and then open a new row, give it a single `td` which spans the entire row, and then put your desired div inside that `td` element. That way the html renderer will understand how the div is supposed to fit into the table structure.

Comment: Thanks for your great idea. Can you give me example ?

Comment: I used `<tr><td colspan="6"></td></tr>` after close the first `td`. But still it's show the hidden content on top.

Comment: Did you put your div inside the `<tr><td colspan="6"></td></tr>`? It should be `<tr><td colspan="6">/* your hidden div */</td></tr>`.

Comment: I'm updating my question please check it.

Comment: and after a load the page it's showing me error message `DataTables warning table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 1. For more information about this error please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`

Comment: I don't think that there's a way to stuff extra content between the rows of the table and still have the rows sortable. I might be wrong, I'm certainly not a bootstrap expert, but it seems to me like it's depending on the assumption that your table is a pretty normal table. You may need to look into a more powerful table API -- I know that Datatables is one that could do what you want and has Bootstrap integration. See here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: Wait, are you using Datatables already? Whoops. In that case -- take a good look at the link I just posted, because it should give you examples of what you need to do.

Comment: Yahoo!!..You gave me a exact link what I need. but It's need to click on a `+` icon. Is it possible to show hidden content by click on entire row !!

Comment: That I don't know, but hopefully someone more experienced in Datatables might turn up, or if not, I think there's a forum on the databtables site? Maybe there'll be more info there. Good luck!